# What exact problem forcing update activation may cause, relating to lazy loading in a Angular PWA app?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to force update activation in a Angular PWA app. The document (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications) has this note:

"*Doing this could break lazy-loading into currently running apps, especially if the lazy-loaded chunks use filenames with hashes, which change every version.*"

What does that note mean? Could you help elaborating how and what problem exactly lazy loading is broken because of forcing update activation?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 4):

I'm not expert on the inner-workings of the Angular SW stuff, but this is the general problem of forcing updates on Service Worker leveraging applications:

1. User opens a page on tab 1 --> SW installs and pre-caches components (chunks) BUT the app *does not* load all components, instead waits for user interaction to load components (chunks)
2. User opens a page on tab 2 --> loads instantly, since SW was installed and pre-cached files were, well, in the cache
3. Developer updates the application someway --> some of the chunks are renamed
4. Developer deploys the application to the server *AND* removes the old versions of the files --> the server now has only the *new versions* of the files *with different chunk names*
5. User uses the app on tab 2 --> force update happens, and when it does, the new SW removes old components (chunks) from the cache and pre-caches new versions of the components
6. User gets back to tab 1 and app tries to lazy-load *an OLD version* of some chunk --> since #5 DELETED the cache from SW and the files DON'T exist on the server anymore, the lazy-load of the chunk fails

Put it simply: if you don't force-update *ALL RUNNING VERSIONS* of the app on all possible tabs in the same browser, a problem might occur where the running JavaScript code tries to lazy-load a chunk that doesn't exist in either the browser cache or in the server.